# Tengo problemas para cambiar mi fondo de escritorio con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Que tal? Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicacion de escritorio. Esta cuenta con una funcion para cambiar el fondo de pantalla del PC. El problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando la ejecuto, en lugar de establecer como fondo de escritorio la imagen que yo indico, este se pone en gris.

La funcion es la siguiente:

```
def setWallpaper(self):

      path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\app\assets\images\wallpaper.jpg"
      changed = win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | win32con.SPIF_SENDCHANGE
      ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(
                           win32con.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path.encode(), changed)
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Tu usuario de windows es realmente "username" ? Porque quizás ese sea el problema. Quizás te interesaría primero comprobar que el archivo existe en la ruta que le indicas antes de cambiar el fondo

Comment: No, no es username, cambie la ruta para subirla aca. ya comprobe que la ruta fuera correcta pero no hay caso. De todas maneras agradezco tu ayuda!

Comment: Python a veces puede ser un poco “tramposo” con las rutas al soportar varios sistemas operativos. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación del módulo ‘pathlib’ que te puede ser útil